# Smooth function, which separates between a closed and a open set.

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, reference-request, manifolds, differential-topology

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, $O\subseteq M$ an open subset and $B\subseteq M$ a closed subset, such that $closure(O)\subseteq interior(B)$

I think there must exist a smooth function $f\colon M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $0\le f\le 1$, $f|_{M-B}\equiv 0$ and $f|_O\equiv 1$, but was not able to find a reference in the general case. (There are many references if $B$ is compact.)

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Prop. 2.2.6 in John M. Lee's "Introduction to Smooth manifolds" (2006 edition)

Comment: I think @John must be referring to the first edition (©2003) of my _Introduction to Smooth Manifolds_. The reference should be Proposition 2.26, not 2.2.6. In the second edition (©2012), it's Proposition 2.25.

Comment: @JackLee : Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @John: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

One reference was supplied by John in a comment, with a correction by Jack Lee:

> Proposition 2.26 in *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* by John M. Lee's, first edition. (Also, Proposition 2.25 of the second edition).

Note that you could just as well consider the disjoint closed sets $\overline{O}$ and $\overline{M\setminus B}$, since the level sets of a continuous function are closed. That is, you are asking for a smooth function separating *two disjoint closed sets*. The search for "smooth Urysohn lemma" and "disjoint closed sets" brings up a few additional results, such as Lemma 1.3.2 in [Manifold Theory](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~petersen/manifolds.pdf) by Peter Petersen.